# Difference between DROP USER and deleting a row from the mysql.user table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-drop

I have a database with hundreds of active connections at any point in time. When I use the DROP USER sql statement to remove a user account, it takes ~4 seconds, during which all other connections have the state "Checking permissions". This means that to delete 1000 users, I'll effectively be locking the database for a good part of 4000 seconds, which is unacceptable. I do notice, however, that deleting a user row from the mysql.users table is instant.

Is deleting a row from mysql.users kosher? What are the drawbacks compared to using DROP USER? Am I leaving stale rows elsewhere? Are there propagation issues? I'm most likely going to have to go this route, but I want to know what other clean up I'll need to do.

Comment: If you issue your 1000 DROP USER statements within a single transaction, does it go faster than 4000 seconds? (I realize that's an absurd number used for illustration, but I'm curious if the time penalty can be taken only once even for multiple drops...)

Comment: Great question. I did in fact test that. Unfortunately, no, the time taken grows proportionally with the number of users being dropped. Edit: This is also the case if multiple users are specified in a single DROP USER command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your version of MySQL

Drop user in `MySQL <= v5.0` only removed the user record but not privileges.
`MySQL >= v5.0.2` does both in a single go.

Also multiple users can be passed.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that DROP USER only removes rows from mysql.user and mysql.tables_priv, and does nothing more?

Comment: Off the top of my head, Drop user replaced the need to Revoke privileges, delete record from user table and flush privileges